# Blender rendering transparent images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am a blender noob, please bare with me

Whenever i render, i get this entire transparent image, nothing showing up. I've already tried changing transparent settings, not using GPU and restarting my computer, none of these worked.

EDIT: i figured out that it seems to be the text scene causing the problem. Swapping around the text and background seems to be working fine. Looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JzGj3mZDCA

My text scene is the only cycles scene i have, rest are in internal engine.

File:
[image]

Reasked, now with file

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't know why but I'm not able to download the .blend...

Comment: Now it should work

Comment: It rendered fine in my computer. The compositing tree is quite complex though, and there may be some issues with it. It did take a long time to process the post production, and while it did nothing displayed in the image viewer, instead a transparent background was in its place giving the impression of an empty render.

Comment: The result was quite disappointing too, a white blur over a black background, so there must definitely something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on my Blender 2.78 and it renders this image:
[image]
Maybe it's what you want. I don't know.
I see the last node (before the composite one, I mean) is a blur.
If I delete it the image is this:
[image]
Is that what you want?

The compositing takes some time to process, and while he does in the Render on the Image Editor window is transparent. Maybe you din't wait enough to complete the compositing.